# Как мы Char переводим в Char?

Tags: java

Не понимаю что происходит в данном поле (см. ниже) - как тут работает элемент - (char).
Просто у нас переменная ch изначально была чаром, как мы чар опять в чар переводим? Объясните пожалуйста популярно пошагово - что происходит в данном поле...

```
public class PobitoviyeOperatory2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char ch;

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            ch = (char) ('A' + i);  //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ МЫ ЧАР В ЧАР ПЕРЕВОДИМ?
            System.out.print(ch);

            ch = (char)((int) ch|32);
            System.out.print(ch + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К вам вопрос: "Каким типом является выражение `('A' + i)` ?"

Comment: В Java определен ряд правил продвижения типов, применяемых к выражениям. Сначала все значения типа byte, short и char продвигаются к типу int. Затем тип всего выражения продвигается к типу long, если 
один из его операндов относится к типу long. Если же один из операндов относится к типу float, то тип всего выражения продвигается к типу float. А если любой из операндов относится к типу double, то и результат вычисления всего выражения относится к типу double.

Comment: Это из Шилдта. Таким образом, в выражении ch = 'A' + i; тип данных будет неявно приведён к int, следовательно нужно выполнить приведение обратно к типу char.

Comment: Понял спасибо))) С неявным преобразованием char в int все сразу понятно)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что каждый char символ имеет свой номер в unicode. В вашем примере происходит неявное приведение к типу int, т.е. к номеру вашей переменной добовляется в цикле значения. Рассмотрим пример:

```
char ch = 'A';
        System.out.println((int) ch);
```

В результате преобразования мы получим номер нашей буквы в unicode. В данном случае 65.
В вашем примере из-за неявного преобразования в цикле к типу int, делается явное преобразование к типу char.

Давайте подробнее разберем ваш пример:

```
public class PobitoviyeOperatory2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char ch;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        ch = (char) ('A' + i);  //неявное преобразование char в int из-за операции сложения, поэтому чтобы вывести букву нужно сделать явное преобразование к типу char
        System.out.print(ch); //выводим букву

        ch = (char)((int) ch|32); //та же буква, но уже нижний регистр 
        System.out.print(ch + " "); //выводим букву
    }}}
```